# jQuery check if the div contains such element before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check with jquery if the div contains such element  before appending. I tried three versions but none of them helped.

Could you please check the commented lines of my code and help me to find the mistake.

```
var item = $('<div>');
var info = $('<a href="http://example.com">'+abc+'</a>');
item.append(info);
var info = $('<a href="http://example.com">'+abc+'</a>');

if (!item.contains(info)) { // first version
if (!item.has(info)) {     // second version
if (!item.find(info).length() > 0) { // third version

item.append(info);
}
```

Comment: `item` is created as `$('<div>')`, how it can contain anything?

Comment: Agreed he has to append child elements in item.

Comment: You can do like this .. `!$("a").has("div")`

Comment: Tushar, I just added some code specially for you, but the problem is only with commented line syntax, you do not need to concentrate your attention on other lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all `<a>`'s in `<div>`'s:

```
var items = $('div a');
```

Now, if you need just `<a>`:

```
if (items == null) { $('div').append('<a></a>'); }
```

else, if you want find exact `<a>`, make a  for loop:

```
var exactHref = "http://...";

if (items == null) {
   var dummy = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
       if (items[i].href == exactHref)
          {
             dummy +=1; 
          }
   }
   if(dummy > 0)
   {
    $('div').append('<a></a>');
   }
}
```

It's not beautiful, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following:

```
if (item.find('a').length == 0) {
    // do your task here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.contains ()` for that.

```
var item=$("<div></div>");
var info = $("<a href=''></a>");
item.append (info);
if (item.contains (info))
{
    //your code
    item.append (info);
}
```

Comment: Tushar I know but I just focused on finding element code. I know as per his code it's not containing any element. He has to use `.append()` for that.

Comment: Just put `!` if you want `false` comparison

Comment: `:contains` is a selector and `.contains()` is a function in jquery.

Comment: Check this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: Change to this `var item = $("<div></div>");item.append ("<a href=''></a>");`